# What containerization methods are actively being worked on for FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, container

What is the state of containerization on FreeBSD as of FreeBSD 12? I've read about a few paths forward so far:

- [Jails](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) -- mature, but not a container mechanism ...
- [Jetpack](https://wiki.freebsd.org/AppContainers) -- There is repository activity but no discussion anywhere about this.
- [Docker](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Docker) -- Maybe stalled/dead? Repository is 6 months stale.
- [Tredly](https://www.reddit.com/r/freebsd/comments/4gggw8/introducing_tredly_containers_for_unix_freebsd/) -- I believe this was a stillborn.

Based on this, it seems that jails is the only option, but jails in itself is just the isolation mechanism. Is there a more comprehensive containerization story being worked on for FreeBSD?

Comment: Jails are very much an container mechanism, one of the originals in a matter of fact. Futher defining what you mean may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Jails are ther containers upon which Linux community based its first chroot based and now LXC (after OpenVZ) based ones. Difference is that jails are much better compartmentalized, so that you can run some of linux distros inside. Jails are on a kernel level. They also have high granularity limits through rctl.

upon trending check iocage and cbsd